# Creating a function to check if two items exists in the table together

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am currently working on this code to check the status of an employee and I want to create a new login function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_status_by_employee_id
(   
p_employee_id       NUMBER 

) RETURN CHAR
AS
  v_status  employee.status%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT status
    INTO   v_status
    FROM   employee
    WHERE  employee_id = p_employee_id;

    return v_status; 

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    return 'N';

END get_status_by_employee_id;
```

New function for the Employee Login:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee_login
(   
p_employee_id       NUMBER,
p_password      VARCHAR2

) RETURN CHAR
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id, password
  FROM employee
  WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;

EXCEPTION 
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
return 'N';

END employee_login;
```

An example test would be:
    SELECT employee_login(2002, 'frw234r')

```
Employee_Login(2002, 'frw234r')
-------------------------------------
F
```

Like in my first function above, if the employee_id is not in the table I want to return 'N'.  If the value of employee_id is in the employee table, but does not match with the p_password I want to return a 'F'. Finally, if the employee_id and p_password match I want to return 'Y'.
I am confused how to implement those last two returns into my code.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function should meet your criteria.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee_login(p_employee_id NUMBER,
                                          p_password  VARCHAR2
) RETURN CHAR
IS
   l_password VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   SELECT password
     INTO l_password
     FROM employee
    WHERE employee_id = p_employee_id;

   IF l_password = p_password THEN
      return 'Y';
   END IF;

   return 'F';

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         return 'N';

END employee_login;
```

Basically, if the NO_DATA_FOUND exception isn't thrown we compare the password you passed in with the password retrieved from the table.  If they match, we return 'Y'. Otherwise we return 'F' to indicate the employee was found, but the password doesn't match.

Comment: OT: It's so good to know that - of course - it's not the actual password that is stored but some good hash value...